# Line, drawn using drawPath is disappearing when panning, though hardware acceleration set to false

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, achartengine

I am facing an issue with drawPath API in android version 4.2. Line disappears sometimes, when panning the canvas. I tried disabling hardware acceleration to false. 
canvas.isHardwareAccelerated() return false.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(tempDrawPoints[0], tempDrawPoints[1]);
path.lineTo(tempDrawPoints[2], tempDrawPoints[3]);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Any idea on this ?

Thanks

JRH

Comment: What about ur paint, can you show some more code ?

Comment: Hi Keshav, Sorry for the delayed reply to this. Actual issue is solved now. I used achartengine for line chart. Issue was there in calculate points for drawPath. That method returns Float.NaN sometimes. So, complete path was missing. I assume Path will not be drawing, if any of the path points is not a Not a number.